# How to test if a Class has been initialized in Visual Basic 6.0

Tags: vb6

Is there a way to test whether a class has been instantiated with VB6? I've tried the following after coming up empty with several Google searches, but neither of these work.

```
If MyClass = "" Then
```

I've even tried:

```
If MyClass Is Nothing Then
```

How do I test whether a class has been initialized or not?

Comment: What's wrong with the `If MyClass Is Nothing Then`?

Comment: GSerg, When I trying this, I remember there being a runtime error (possibly 91), that said that highlighted `Nothing` in my code. I thought VB6 didn't use this keyword.

Comment: VB6 uses that keyword.

Comment: I just tried `Is Nothing` and I don't see anymore errors. If you want to post this answer, I'll accept it for you. Thank you, GSerg

Comment: GSerg, is there an online resource that you can point me to that might help me with basic syntax?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/visual-basic-language-reference

Comment: Is it the documentation for VB6? I've had issues before on Microsoft's site with not finding documentation that is specifically for VB6. There is plenty of information on .net it seems, but those commands won't work in VB6

Comment: That is for VBA. It is not absolutely 100% VB6, but by the time you start stumbling upon the differences, you will be able to resolve them easily with your experience.

Comment: Okay, that's good to know. Thanks, GSerg!! In the meantime, please put up with me here, I'm almost done making mods to this application. Thank you for the help!

Comment: VB6 hosts the VBA language. VB6 add it own forms package and a application object. So any language reference will take you to a VBA documentation page, any object from VB will take to a VB6 documentation page. Press F2 in VB6 (or office VBA editor) and you will see the VB library which is Forms and Application object, the VBA library which is the language, and VBRUN library which supports classes events and databinding.

Comment: Since this question seems to be about VB6 syntax and programming concepts I think its worth pointing out to the OP that you do not / cannot test a "class" for initialization, but an object.  So your code should be something like:   `Dim MyObject as MyClass` and later `If MyObject Is Nothing Then ... `

Answer (score 3):

Since I can't yet comment to the thread, the complete MS documentation for VB6 can still be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-basic-6/visual-basic-6.0-documentation?irgwc=1&OCID=AID2000142_aff_7795_1243925&tduid=%28ir__ubb1az0gjkkft09oxka03fe3c22xnqqyu3hgncyj00%29%287795%29%281243925%29%28je6NUbpObpQ-8.0ZechC6m88C0FYTdXPZA%29%28%29&irclickid=_ubb1az0gjkkft09oxka03fe3c22xnqqyu3hgncyj00#visual-basic-60-documentationaa232759vvs60md?ranMID=43674&ranEAID=je6NUbpObpQ&ranSiteID=je6NUbpObpQ-8.0ZechC6m88C0FYTdXPZA&epi=je6NUbpObpQ-8.0ZechC6m88C0FYTdXPZA

Comment: John, thank you!! This is exactly what I spent so much time trying to find. This is specifically for VB6. I'm hoping this will help. Thank you again for posting this!